# How to design document/content application where URI should be used for selecting content

Tags: php, web-applications, apache2, apache

I am trying to figure out how to design an application which has documents(in html-format)/content in a directory structure. What I want is that the URL should decide which document that should be presented. E.g. www.mydomain.com/docs/read_this should in some way help me present content named "read_this".

I also want the possibility for the users to make a full search of the docs. First, I had the intent of storing all docs in MySQL and user the built in support for full search. But I got stuck in how to solve the URI vs. content problem. Since it should be possible to create or edit content I though that storing it in the database would make it easier than putting it in files as well.

This is the normal way of doing it, many sites implement it like this. Still, I cannot find anything about how to solve it. Perhaps the words used for googling is to similar to other info; document, directory, structure, content, URI, etc...

I am using Apache/httpd and PHP on CentOS 6.2.

What is the approach for solving above mentioned problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost creating a REST interface, but since you're wanting to serve the documents directly, it's not quite.

I'd suggest a structure like:

- `http://example.com/docs/`: Root level of your application (shows some info about the app
- `http://example.com/docs/view/read_this`: Show the document named "read_this"
- `http://example.com/docs/search/keyword`: Show a list of documents that contain the keyword "keyword"

Adding the "view" and "search" parent "folders" prevents collision; if you just had `http://example.com/docs/read_this` as the document view schema (and left the search schema as-is), you could never have a document named `search` since that would collide with the special `search` term. You also mentioned editing, which could be done with a `http://example.com/edit/read_this` schema.

In order to make all these URIs resolve, you'd need to use Mod_Rewrite in your Apache config to point them at your PHP script.

**EDIT:** Here's the `.htaccess` and PHP link needed

### .htaccess:

This goes in the root of your `docs` folder, alongside `index.php`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?action=$1&target=$2 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

This technically means that people could enter the URL `http://example.com/docs/view/read_this` or `http://example.com/docs/index.php?action=view&target=read_this` and get the same result

### index.php:

```
<?php
$action = (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] != '')? $_GET['action'] : false;
$target = (isset($_GET['target']) && $_GET['target'] != '')? $_GET['target'] : false;
switch($action) {
  case 'view':
    viewDoc($target); // Do your view logic here
    break;
  case 'search':
    doSearch($target); // Do your search logic here
    break;
  case 'foobar':
    // Add new functionality here
    break;
  default:
    errorOut('No such action as '.$action);
    break;
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! Ok, so rewriting is the common solution for this? Is your idea that the view, search and edit part of the URI should be used when rewriting in order to direct to appropriate php file?

Comment: The common practice is to redirect everything to a single PHP file and have the PHP file then determine what to do with the input. I've added an example that not only redirects `view` and `search`, but all other lower-case keywords. If the action keyword is unknown, PHP can create a graceful error page.

Comment: Greate, I'll look into it and get back here.

Comment: I made the decision to configure the rewriting in httpd.conf since I don't have the need to distribute the application and apparently it's better performance as well. However, something is wrong in my rewrite rule. Any suggestions? RewriteRule ^docs/([a-z]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/docs/index.php?action=$1&target=$2 [QSA,L]

Comment: There were some errors in your rewrite rule @MidnightLightning. You can read about it here [RewriteRule question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422551/mod-rewrite-dont-match-on-rewritecond-target-url-not-found/12424525#12424525) I didn't mention that my setup is multi virtual hos, it may be reason to some of the problems.

Comment: This is actually answered already, but do you know, @MidnightLightning, if google can index the text in the docs when using this solution?

Comment: If you create a proper [sitemap](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156184) and include all the `/view` URLs, then search engines will find them. Google indexes PDFs, not all search engines do. If you serve up Word Docs or anything other than text or PDFs, the words themselves won't get indexed.

Comment: The text is rendered as normal html. I though sitemaps wasn't needed anymore and that google could find it all self (if the web application is structured with all links pointing to all content inside the app at least). I do have a page which I know google recognize which points to all docs, I guess I don't need a sitemap then, do I? My concern is if something happens when doing the rewrite that destroys the possibility for google to read the content?

Comment: If you just have static text links to everything, likely Google and other search engines (don't forget there are others out there too) can follow those just fine. The Sitemap protocol is a strict structure that search engine scripts then *KNOW* the structure of the site, rather than having to feel it out.

Comment: Is it considered a static link when I do a rewrite to something like this as you suggested: http://example.com/docs/index.php?action=view&target=read_this ? Or will it be dynamic and ignored by google (or other search engines)?

Comment: Here they discuss the topic but only when one is doing the other way around, rewriting a dynamic link to something that looks more static: [Google and dynamic links](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.se/2008/09/dynamic-urls-vs-static-urls.html)

Comment: If you link to your pages using the static, `view/doc_id` structure, that is what Google will index. The mod_rewrite rule will never expose the dynamic URL to the visitor; the URL should stay the same in their address bar. Technically if you visit the dynamic URL it would work, but Google wouldn't parse it properly, so don't publish/link to the pages that way.

Comment: I guess we are moving out of topic with this discussion here... So it doesn't matter that in the browser's address bar, the URL is actually changed upon a rewrite, is google (and perhaps other search engines) still indexing on the entered URL? If that were the case, would google have problems in some rewrite situation which is discussed in the link I provided? According to the link I provided dynamic URLs can be indexed properly, under certain conditions I think. Well, perhaps I should create a new post...

Comment: @Nicsoft No, that's not correct. It does matter what's in the browser bar. If you use a `RewriteRule` by default, it will **not** change the URL in the address bar. Adding `[R=301]` to the end of the rule turns it into a *redirect* that **does** change the URL. Advertising rewritten URLs that make them look static to search engines is a better way to ensure they all get indexed.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is commonly called a RESTful URI.  There are too many ways to implement this to say "here's the right way".

For example, if you use apache and you only want this sort of mapping to occur for URIs of the form `www.mydomain.com/docs/read_this` then you could have an `.htaccess` in the docs folder that redirects (via [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)) all requests to a single php script (like docs/index.php) which could then dissect the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` variable to get the document name that was in the URI (`read_this`) and then request the appropriate document from your mysql DB.

Comment: Thanks! This sounds like something. Can you see any negative things doing this in the httpd.conf (redirect all URI = /docs/...)?

Comment: Not sure if I'm qualified to answer that, I barely started learning apache when my site moved to nginx so my knowlege of apache is limited.  That said, .htaccess is kinda of a last ditch effort to handle a specific directory, i used it because I only had access to my 'personal' directory on the site.  I would assume handling it at a higher level is better.

Comment: Ok, I think you are correct. I'll try that...tomorrow. I'll get back once I have tried it out.

Comment: Putting the configuration in your `httpd.conf` makes the application less portable; if you ever want to duplicate/move the application to another server, you not only have to remember to move your PHP files from `/docs/`, but also remember that *part* of `httpd.conf` is valid for that project. If you just use an `.htaccess` file inside the `docs` folder, all project files are then within that folder for easy backup/copying.

Comment: In nginx you can put site specific stuff into its own file and then import it into the main config file, can you do something similar with httpd.conf?

Comment: @Matt Apache can have multiple `.conf` files defining its core configuration, but usually those supplement `.conf` files are not kept in the same folder as the web content. So that removes the problem of having *part* of a file be relevant, but you still have project files scattered among multiple, separate, folders of the server.

Comment: Oh, and one other caveat: If you modify .conf files, you have to restart apache. If you use htaccess files, you don't. That makes a huge difference on production servers.